# What is the best way to add multiple onTap events in listview flutter?

Tags: listview, flutter

````
Widget _myListView(BuildContext context) {

  final titles = ['bike', 'boat', 'bus', 'car',
    'railway', 'run', 'subway', 'transit', 'walk'];

  final icons = [Icons.directions_bike, Icons.directions_boat,
    Icons.directions_bus, Icons.directions_car, Icons.directions_railway,
    Icons.directions_run, Icons.directions_subway, Icons.directions_transit,
    Icons.directions_walk];

  final ontaps = [ ,] ```how can i add multiple onTap events ```

  return ListView.builder(
    itemCount: titles.length,
    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
      return Card( //                           <-- Card widget
        child: ListTile(
          leading: Icon(icons[index]),
          title: Text(titles[index]),
          onTap: ,
        ),
      );
    },
  );
}
````

PLease help me  How can I add onTap events easily for a long list

1.How can I add onTap events the way I added Icons, Heading,sub heading using Strings 
2.I Am new to flutter please pardon my errors.. Thank you

Comment: Are you targeting any specific widget for tap ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uptdated answer, now it navigates to other page if you tab bike:

main.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:prova/page.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      routes: {
        'other_page': (BuildContext context) => Example(),
      },
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Demo'),
      ),
      body: _myListView(context),
    );
  }
}

Widget _myListView(BuildContext context) {
  final titles = [
    'bike',
    'boat',
    'bus',
    'car',
    'railway',
    'run',
    'subway',
    'transit',
    'walk'
  ];

  final icons = [
    Icons.directions_bike,
    Icons.directions_boat,
    Icons.directions_bus,
    Icons.directions_car,
    Icons.directions_railway,
    Icons.directions_run,
    Icons.directions_subway,
    Icons.directions_transit,
    Icons.directions_walk
  ];

  functionBike() {
    Navigator.pushNamed(context, 'other_page');

    print('directions_bike');
  }

  functionBoat() {
    print('directions_boat');
  }

  functionBus() {
    print('directions_bus');
  }

  functionCar() {
    print('directions_car');
  }

  functionRailway() {
    print('directions_railway');
  }

  functionRun() {
    print('directions_run');
  }

  functionSubway() {
    print('directions_subway');
  }

  functionTransit() {
    print('directions_transit');
  }

  functionWalk() {
    print('directions_walk');
  }

  final List<Function> ontaps = [
    functionBike,
    functionBoat,
    functionBus,
    functionCar,
    functionRailway,
    functionRun,
    functionSubway,
    functionTransit,
    functionWalk
  ];

  return ListView.builder(
    itemCount: titles.length,
    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
      return Card(
        //                           <-- Card widget
        child: ListTile(
          leading: Icon(icons[index]),
          title: Text(titles[index]),
          onTap: () {
            ontaps[index]();
          },
        ),
      );
    },
  );
}
```

Hope it help.

Comment: I AM SURE YOUR METHOD IS GOING TO WORK... BUT What I will write instead of  print ('  ')      // I tried using Navigator.push   but it is not working

Comment: It should work, I have a working demo of your project and it navigate to the route, will update my answer.

Comment: Thank you very much...your code worked ...//But  I used  Navigator.push(
        context, new MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => new RamBike()));
  }     THIS instead of   NAVIGATOR.PUSHNAMED  ////// Navigator.Pushnamed does not work for this listview

Comment: Use:  functionBike() {
    Navigator.push(
      context,
      MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) {
        return RamBike();
      }),
    );

    print('directions_bike');
  }

Comment: Happy to hear, you may check the answer as solved ;-)

Comment: Error shows when I tried this method for a 15 line list..setState() or markNeedsBuild() called during build.    This overlay widget can not be marked as needing to build because the framework is already in the process of building widgets. A widget can be marked has needing to be built during the build phase only if one of its ancestors is currently building.This exception is allowed because the framework builds parent widgets before children,which means a dirty descendant will always be built.otherwise,the framework might not visit this widget during build phase

Comment: Is like your functions are trying to get invoked in build fase, can I see a bit of your code?

Answer (score 1):

To add onTap event for all your widgets in your listtile you can use the code below,

```
             return ListView.builder(
                    itemCount: titles.length,
                    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                      return Card( //                           <-- Card widget
                        child: ListTile(
                          leading: IconButton(icon: Icon(icons[index]),onPressed: (){
                            // add your code on tap for your iconButton
                          },),
                          title: Text(titles[index]),
                          onTap: (){
                            // add your code on tap for your listview row tile
                          },
                        ),
                      );
                    },
                  );
```

This will work for you.

Comment: I am a beginner level coder.. I do not know what you are saying... How can I add multiple tap events inside onTap ? please see The answer of DANIEL to my question  //  Daniel answer matches to my expectation but still i remain unable to add onTap events using Navigator.push method